# Siemens Openness XML files

Tags: xml, plc, siemens

So Im working on automating the development of PLC code that is expressed in XML, and to do so I have exported FB block and its networks to see what the code looks like so I could get an Idea of the XML tree But there is a tag called <SW.Blocks.CompileUnit **ID="DD"** CompositionName="CompileUnits"> and I could not figure Out how does the compiler assigns the value I tryied looking if it was HEX but I dont see the relation. The next assigened value is <SW.Blocks.CompileUnit **ID="E6"** CompositionName="CompileUnits"> Help on this matter would be very much apprecciated.

Comment: Has it to be Siemens?As for now I don't know about this topic in Siemens but I could help you out on this topic with another PLC brand like Beckhoff PLC...

Answer (score 1):

Don’t worry too much about the IDs! All the IDs in this XML-Files has to be unique. They don’t have to be in order or something. So, when you generate code use a simple counter for the IDs to make sure they are unique and that’s it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

The compiler assigns the CompileUnit IDs according to the wisdom of its own internal logic, which is not of consequence in the only application worth considering - generating blocks to import, as IchEben has *correctly* pointed out.

CompileUnit ID must be numeric (hex or dec), unique and possibly incremental, as per this xslt definition in the Siemens example C# project "OpennessExcelSwGenerator", SIOS ID 109770550 (comments translated using DeepL):

```
<!--Variable "pos" counts the number of networks to get a consecutive unique ID for each network within this document-->
      <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
      <!--Variable "pos" used as ID-->
          <SW.Blocks.CompileUnit ID="{$pos}" CompositionName="CompileUnits">
      ...
```

Other than that, documentation is scant - I've searched for this myself a couple of times.  You could try looking through SIOS in case I missed something:
[Siemens Industry Support Online](https://support.industry.siemens.com/)

If you must know how the **TIA compiler** generates those IDs, you can raise a support request on SIOS.  I guess they'll elevate the question to the dev team, but you risk annoying them for something they certainly won't think you need to know.